# I have completely wiped out my SSD, how do I install new OS?

Tags: boot, ssd, kali-linux, dualboot, disk-cleanup

I had dual boot with Windows 11 and Kali. I have completely wiped out the SSD & as I wanted to start fresh. But as I turn on the computer it says
"Boot Media not found (032) Please install an operating system."
Now when I insert a bootable USB then the BIOS says nothing.
What have I done exactly? And how do I make everything normal ?
Please, I am in serious trouble.
Please help.
Thank in advance

Comment: You need to make a Windows 11 USB Boot Disk from the Microsoft Media Creation Link for Windows 11. Use the link to download and make a disk, You might need Rufus. You may need to go into BIOS (UEFI) and disable Secure Boot.

Comment: Also, in the category of "been there, done that", I would *suggest* either running kali in a VM or through the WSL-2 "Win-KeX".  You can also run Kali as the primary and windows as the VM.  If your machine is sufficiently beefy (it is, it runs 11), this is SO MUCH EASIER with *very little* performance degradation.  If I go full screen on my VMs, I don't even know that I am using one.  You also don't need to play the partition or boot loader game.

Comment: Yes - Posted from my Kali 2022.1 Virtual Machine.